# C# foreach loop between 2 values

Tags: c#, foreach, int, port, visual-c#-express-2010

How can I use a `foreach` statement to loop between 2 values given by the user?

I am making an application that scans for ports, so I want the user to specify which ports to search for; here is some example code that dose not function, but should help you understand what I am looking for:

```
int port1 = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
int port2 = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

foreach(int between port1 and port2)
{
  //do something 
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 9):

No, foreach is for iterating over a collection. What you want is a for loop.

```
int port1 = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
int port2 = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

for(var i = port1; i <= port2; i++)
{
  //do something 
}
```

Comment: This is simple, and answers the question - it should be accepted.  +1  Good Job.

Answer (score 6):

AlexD's answer is on the right track, but unfortunately misuses the second parameter of `Enumerable.Range`.  The second parameter is `count`, not a bound for the range.

It should read:

```
Enumerable.Range(port1, (port2 - port1) + 1)
```

or if you don't know if port1 is less than port2:

```
Enumerable.Range(Math.Min(port1, port2), Math.Abs(port2 - port1) + 1)
```